# Physical difference between Microcanonical and canonical ensemble

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, statistical-mechanics, temperature

While performing a molecular dynamics simulation, what is physically different between holding the total energy constant and temperature constant? I have seen MD simulation studies where particle velocities attain an equilibrium distribution (Boltzmann) where the total energy was constant. But, according to my knowledge, it is true when the temperature is held fixed. Can someone clarify if I'm going wrong somewhere?

Comment: Temperature(inverse) is the  Lagrange multiplier under constraint $E_{mean}=const$ - mean energy is constant

Comment: To do molecular dynamics simulations in the canonical ensemble, you would have to model the exchange of energy of a system with an external temperature bath, making sure that detailed balance is obeyed.  Since the results are known to be the same either way (in the thermodynamic limit), the added complication generally does nothing to improve the calculation.

Comment: @Buzz The ensembles become equivalent as the number of particles goes to infinity (scaling of fluctuations being something like 1/sqrt(N)), so you do want to simulate with the correct ensemble - also the experimental condition is that of fixed temperature usually. Loads of methods for this, Nose-Hoover most prominently. Similar considerations come into play with fixed volume vs pressure ensembles, too.

Comment: The question OP was not about the details of the simulation, but the physical difference. The case of a fixed temperature means  *an average*  energy constant instead of  *a total* energy constant